# Need to make an auto exec batch file

Tags: python

So its for a python script, no idea where to start for it lol. the script i'm using sometimes randomly stops and i need the batch file to automatically re run it whenever it stops.

I guess i need to make something with like fdos so like, i run the script, and lets say the batch file every 1 or 2 hours it restarts itself so i can always have it running without worrying about it stopping randomly.

Please help <3.

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide a more coherent [mcve] to your problem. You need to provide the proper technical details around what you tried to do so readers here take this question more seriously. As is, this is extremely broad and not helpful to anyone who wants to help.

Comment: Not being funny, but if you want good answers you need to take more pride in your question. At the moment it looks like you don't care. See [ask].

Comment: I have an answer for this if you [edit] your question and rewrite it a bit as already suggested. Tag me back for more of my time when you take a crack at that!!

Answer (score 2):

You could specify an `atexit` handler in your python script:

```
import atexit
import os

def exit_handler():
    os.system("C:/Path/To/batch.bat")

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Where test.bat contains:

```
Python C:/Path/To/python.py
```

However, this will also cause the script to start up again if it exits legitimately.

Perhaps if you could identify what exit code is sent when it exits "randomly", you can check for that exitcode in `atexit` and start the batch file up if it matches your problematic exit code.

Comment: oh its meant to run 24/7, but it just randomly stops sometimes and just displays numbers like this: 4567, 4568 etc every second

Comment: In that case the above should work for you (if you need to to run constantly), but if by "stopping randomly" you mean it continues but displays the wrong behaviour, then you will need to give more details